# Build V8 with GN and MinGW

Tags: mingw, v8, mingw-w64, embedded-v8, gn

I would like to build a static, monolithic library suitable for embedding via MinGW. This is a multiplatform project and I want to avoid switching my entire toolchain over to MSVC. All answers on StackOverflow, Google Groups and the v8 wiki refer to SCons, GYP or MinGW build generation files that no longer exist. I have:

1. Followed the instructions [here](https://v8.dev/docs/build) to install depot_tools and fetch v8.
2. Added `[User Directory]\depot_tools` to the front of my PATH variable.
3. Set `DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0` in my environment variables.

Instructions [here](https://v8.dev/docs/build-gn) suggest bypassing the manual workflow by outputting build files yourself. When I run `gn args out/mingw` I get a python stack trace ending with:

```
Exception: No supported Visual Studio can be found. Supported versions are: 16.0 (2019), 17.0 (2022), 15.0 (2017).
ERROR at //build/config/win/visual_studio_version.gni:27:7: Script returned non-zero exit code.
      exec_script("../../vs_toolchain.py", [ "get_toolchain_dir" ], "scope")
      ^----------
```

Comment: I wish they would just use cmake or meson...

Comment: Why don't use pre-built https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-v8?repo=mingw64?

Comment: @BrechtSanders: we accept patches, but maintaining another build system doesn't have sufficiently high priority for us to spend time on it, so you'd have to do that on an ongoing basis. (And we can't "just" switch either, for various reasons.)

Comment: @273K: one possible reason: those packages are pretty outdated.

Comment: @DragonDePlatino: I believe it should be enough to have the "Windows SDK" installed, possibly as part of a MSVC installation. V8 certainly doesn't require the MSVC compiler (but does support it optionally); we compile with our own bundled Clang by default, including on Windows. (I don't know the specifics of MinGW these days, haven't tried it in a while, and don't have time to dig into it.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, since you mentioned `gn` specifically. But a few months ago I managed to compile V8 using `gm.py` and following [these instructions](https://v8.dev/docs/build-gn#gm).

This is what I did (I keep all git repos in `~/repos`):

```
mkdir ~/repos/v8/v8 # that's right, type v8 twice
git checkout main

# update V8
git pull

# update V8 dependencies
gclient sync

# compile source
tools/dev/gm.py x64.release
# or, compile source and immediately run the tests
tools/dev/gm.py x64.release.check
```

If you need to set some specific V8 compile-time flags, I think you cannot use `gm.py` though. You need to generate build files using either gn or `v8gen.py`:

- https://v8.dev/docs/build-gn#gn
- https://v8.dev/docs/build-gn#v8gen

After you have managed to generate the build files, you can finally [compile V8 using ninja](https://v8.dev/docs/build-gn#compile).

A completely different route could be to use [zig-v8](https://github.com/fubark/zig-v8), which uses the Zig toolchain to build V8. For example, [Cosmic](https://github.com/fubark/cosmic/) is a JS/WASM runtime that uses zig-v8 to embed V8.